# Accessing Router Remotely

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am a landlord with a house with two suites. I pay for 2 separate internet connections. From time to time, I need to access either router to do maintenance, such as restart the router or change the wifi passwords.

However, I don't know  how to access 192.168.1.254 from an external location. Can someone help me set this up? I believe I need to port forward to 192.168.1.254 but can someone explain how. Thanks!

Comment: Almost all routers today allow for remote management.  But it's hard to give you instructions without knowing the make & model of the router.  Post that, and someone should be easily able to give you specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to access 192.168.1.254 from an external location because it is a class C private IP address. In otherwords, you wouldn't be able to access it from your other suite.

More information on IP addresses can be found here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

To answer your question, how can you manage the router remotely, you can do one of two things: 
1) Install logmein or some other software on your computer in your other suite and access that remote computer first via logmein and then access your router from this remote computer. This is safer.

2) Log into the router you are trying to administer and look for some option that says, "Allow WAN management" or "Remote Administration" Once you enable remote administration, you would be able to login from anywhere using your PUBLIC IP address. You can figure out your public IP address by visiting: http://www.whatismyip.com
Beware, this will allow you to control your device from anywhere, it will also allow hackers to be able to brute force your login and login as well.

Hope it helps. Feel free to ask for additional help!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to allow access to the web interface of th eoruter from th eexternal IP. But don't do that unless you are sure you can restrict this service to requests coming from your site!

Alternatively, the suite routers and your own may be configured to connnect via virtual private network (VPN). But don't do that unless you are sure you know how to separate the two local nets (grant privacy to your guests and also protect you from attacks issued *by* your guests)!

In all scenarios, one problem may be tha tyour different internet connections are likely to change their public IP addrresses on a regular basis. You'd need to configure something like dyndns to "find" the other end.